cmake compile same target with different compiler options
I have a static library that is used simultaneously in an executable program and as a part of shared library.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(mve)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(staticLib STATIC library.h library.cpp)

add_executable(exe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exe PUBLIC staticLib)

add_library(sharedLib SHARED lib.h lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sharedLib PUBLIC staticLib)

So, the shared library absolutely requires the static library to be compiled with -fPIC, whereas it is said that executable is better off without it.
What are the ways to set up cmake to satisfy both of those conditions?

Since you'll have to rebuild the library with the different options, I think the only way to achieve this is to create two different targets:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(mve)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(staticLibPIC STATIC library.h library.cpp)
set_property(TARGET staticLibPIC PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON) # Enables -fPIC

add_library(staticLibNoPIC STATIC library.h library.cpp)
set_property(TARGET staticLibNoPIC PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE OFF)

add_executable(exe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exe PUBLIC staticLibNoPIC)

add_library(sharedLib SHARED lib.h lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sharedLib PUBLIC staticLibPIC)

